# How can I get the selected date from datepicker to the method in backend

Tags: javascript, java, html, intellij-idea, datepicker

I have a datepicker in my UI. using that I can select date. My probelem is how can I get that selected date into my backend which is developing in java.
 Can it do using javascript or any other method.

This is my code

```
<input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="datepickerlog">
<script>
    $('#datepickerlog').datepicker()
</script>
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: added to the question

Answer (score 1):

```
var selectedDate = $("#datepickerlog").val();
```

This will read the date from your text input and assign it to the variable "selectedDate".

Edit: Place it inside your datepicker like this to assign date to variable when datepicker is closed:

```
$('#datepickerlog').datepicker({
    onClose: function (dateText) {
            var selectedDate = $("#datepickerlog").val();
            }
    });
```

Edit #2: To avoid problems with your script not doing what you expect, I suggest putting all jQuery code inside this function:

```
$( function() {---your code here---});
```

This way you can be sure that your script only runs after the page is loaded and ready for script execution.

Comment: That depends on a lot of different things. I can't give you an answer to that question without knowing some details about your backend.